# specific turtles name on same patch

Tags: netlogo

I'm quite new to Netlogo and am having difficulty with getting the turtles to change direction. I am trying to get my turtle to walk towards a 'bed' (which is a different breed of turtle) and then once it has arrived change direction. 
This is what I have tried (as well as many other possibilities!)

```
if location = bed 3 [
  face bed 0
  if turtle-here = bed 0 [
    set location bed 0 
    forward 1
    stop
  ]
]
if location = bed 0 [
  face bed 4
  if turtle-here = bed 4 [
    set location bed 4 
    forward 1
    stop
  ]
]
```

It continues further to make a cyclic path. I think the problem is that when I'm asking about 'turtle-here' it will report true or false or give me a number, when what I need is the turtles name. But I can't find any primitives that will do that.

Any Ideas??

Thanks 
Naomi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing `if turtle-here = bed 0` with `if member? bed 0 turtles-here` should fix it.

Not sure what you mean by a turtle's "name".

I recommend you look at Move Towards Target Example, in the Code Examples section of the Models Library.  It's extremely similar to what you're trying to do.